# Google App Engine Remote API Service Account Credential error

Tags: google-app-engine, service

I am currently using remote api for google app engine to connect to a datastore from another GAE project.

Below is my code:

RemoteApiOptions options;

```
    options = new RemoteApiOptions().server("project_id.appspot.com",443).useServiceAccountCredential("project@project-168016.iam.gserviceaccount.com","EPHIMS-cbe10d4a5105.json");

RemoteApiInstaller installer = new RemoteApiInstaller();
installer.install(options);
```

When I run my application, I get the error below:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to build service account credential. 
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: EPHIMS-cbe10d4a5105.json (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)

Does anyone know how to fix this? - I have created an environment variable and set it to the path where the .json file is, this still does not work.

Comment: In your project structure, where do you keep this file?

Comment: Hi I keep it under the war directory.